# Discord Py | Add Role to Specific Person

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js, roles

I want to add a specific role to a specific user everytime a value in my double arrays is reached. I've tried this and many more but nothing seems to work. Here's my actual code:

```
bot.on('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    for (let i = 0; i < Membres.length; i++) {
        if (Membres[i][1]==100000){
            let memberRole = message.member.roles.find("Pirate");
            message.guild.get_member("my id").addRole(memberRole);
            //message.channel.sendMessage("Félicitations tu deviens pirate !");
            //let memberRole = member.guild.roles.find(Pirate);
            //message.server.get_member("391581984956350465").addRole(memberRole);
        }
    }
```

And here's the error, I'm getting :

````
    if (typeof value === 'undefined') throw new Error('Value must be specified.');
                                      ^

Error: Value must be specified.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found

```
for (let i = 0; i < Membres.length; i++) {
        switch (Membres[i][1]){
            case 100000:
                const memberRole = message.guild.roles.find('name', "Pirate"); 
                const member1 = message.guild.members.get(id);
                member1.addRole(memberRole); 
                break;
        }
    }
```